# Testing file input streams in java

Tags: java, testing

```
@Override
public Collection<Flight> getAll() {
    try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)))) {
        Object read = ois.readObject();
        List<Flight> objects   = (ArrayList<Flight>) read;
        return objects;
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

@Test
public void testGetAll() {
    try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("flights.txt")))) {
        Object read = ois.readObject();
        expected = (ArrayList<Flight>) read;
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    Collection<Flight> actual = flightService.getAll();
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

Hi I have serious problem with testing. Is the above code a correct way to test? Please help me

Comment: No, that's not a good way to test it; it duplicates the code rather than setting up a proper environment where the result is predictable and then checking that. Where does the `file` come from in the `getAll()` method?

Comment: Yah i felt it, it is wrong(.... getAll() got file from same place which Collection<Flight> get.. Both take file form "flights.txt"

Comment: What I meant is, how is `file` initialized in the tested class. Is the file path passed to it, or is it some constant value.

Comment: i dont initialize any file in tested class.there is one file which located in project.and I read these file in both case (expected and actual). Should I initilaze new file in test class?

Comment: I don't mean the file itself, I mean the `file` variable (containing the file path). Is it passed to the class in a constructor or set via some method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So say your class is given the file to read in the constructor, like this:

```
class FlightReader {
    File file;
    public FlightReader(File f) {
        file = f;
    }
    // your getAll here
}
```

then a test would first create a file of its own with known data, then read it, then verify the results are as expected, like this:

```
@Test
public void testGetAll() {
    Flight f1 = new Flight("ACREG1", "B737");
    Flight f2 = new Flight("ACREG2", "A320");
    Flight f3 = new Flight("ACREG3", "B777");
    List<Flight> written = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(f1, f2, f3));
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("flights", "test");
    // write sample data
    try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tempFile))) {
        oos.writeObject(written);
    }

    // data is written to a file, read it back using the tested code
    FlightReader reader = new FlightReader(tempFile);
    List<Flight> readFlights = reader.getAll();

    // verify the written and read data are the same
    assertThat(readFlights).contains(f1, f2, f3);
}
```

Some notes:

- you should use specific classes - like in this case `ArrayList` - as little as possible. Why cast to an `ArrayList` if you just return a `Collection` in the end?
- you shouldn't use Java Serialization at all; it's error-prone, a security risk, and considered a mistake by the Java architects.

Comment: So it can create another file

Comment: and we will read this file ,and check if getall contains correct object yes?

Comment: What is FlightReader here?

Comment: @SamirAllahverdiyev `FlightReader` is the name I gave your class to be tested since you didn't mention it. The `Flight` class needs a properly defined `equals () ` method for this to work.

Comment: Yeap I get it Thanksss